# searching all id between two values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like using the entity manager
Find all id between 1 and 100, for example:

I'm really stuck who can help me

```
$em = $this-> getDoctrine() -> getEntityManager();
$KPII = $em-> getRepository('AdminBlogBundle: AlertesBss2') -> findBy(array ('id' =>)
```

Comment: this doesnt look valid "KPII $"

Comment: Hm, I never seen so many syntax errors in two lines of code. In general you seem to have bad writting habits (putting spaces between function/method name and brackets, putting spaces around `$`, putting `$` after variable name... Is it really your code (or at least code you understand)?

Comment: Have a read through the [manual about querying](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects) It tells you all you need to solve this, and you will be better off after solving it yourself.

Comment: I used this link but I haven't found what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```php
$em
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT u.name 
          FROM User u 
         WHERE u.id BETWEEN :from AND :to'
    )
    ->setParameters([
        'from' => $form,
        'to'   => $to,
    ])
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: or use the <PHP5.4 `array(...)` variant instead of the newer `[...]` syntax.